# How to allocate memory of a struct?

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to allocate memory and zero it out for the sender struct but I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly. I'm trying to learn how to manage memory in C while I am doing this project. How can I test it to see what I set the memory to?  And will what I am trying to do work, or is there a better way of doing this?

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

typedef struct {
    uchar Seq;
    uchar Ack;
    uchar Flags;
} Header;

#define FRAME_PAYLOAD_SIZE 50
struct Frame_t
{
    Header header;
    char data[FRAME_PAYLOAD_SIZE];
    uchar CRC;
};
typedef struct Frame_t Frame;

struct Sender
{
    uchar winSize;

    struct sendSlot {
        struct timeval timeout;
        Frame msg;
    } sendQ[5];
};


    initSend(Sender* sender) {
        sender->winSize = -1;

        char* send_buf = (char*) malloc(5 * sizeof(sender->sendQ[0]));
        memset(send_buf, 0, 5 * sizeof(sender->sendQ[0]));
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<sizeof(sender->sendQ)/sizeof(sender->sendQ[0]); i++) {
             memset(sender->sendQ[i].timeout, 0, sizeof(struct timeval));
            sender->sendQ = NULL;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a function inside `main()`? If so, stop right there.

Comment: Just use [`calloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of `malloc`, and you'll start with zeroed-out memory. Problem solved!

Comment: @EOF no, main is not important here, initSend() could be within any other file.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc`.

Comment: @Urler: Well, your code is not c. Why did you tag this as c if you want to define a function inside of a function?

Comment: @EOF sorry I was using ideone.com so I will edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: `typedef uchar unsigned char` is not a valid `typedef` for what you likely want to achieve, and it's missing the semicolon. Please post real code.

Comment: @melpomene - If you offer advice like this, you should be clear. In C, you should not cast *the result of `malloc`*—or any other `void*` value—when assigning to another pointer type, because the compiler does the conversion for you.

Comment: @unwind fixed, thanks.

Comment: As pointed out, `calloc` will give you zeroed memory. But just for your learning, if you `memset` a structure then that sets all fields within the struct including nested structs. So in your case you don't need to `memset` the `timeout` field again.

Comment: Maybe you want to say :  typedef struct Frame Frame_t;  instead of : typedef struct Frame_t Frame;

Comment: @BobRun fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendQ` is an array member of `Sender`, it is not a pointer.
There is no need for allocating memory using `malloc`. You can use:

```
initSend(Sender* sender) {
   sender->winSize = -1;
   memset(sender->sendQ, 0, sizeof(sender->sendQ));
}
```

Comment: Why not just `void initSend(Sender *sender){Sender s = {.winSize = -1}; *sender = s; return;}`?